# Manage javascript scope in ajax application via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I wonder how to manage the script scope on a full ajax application

Let me explain a scenario

- Pages are loaded dynamically in a div,
- pages are php files
- pages contains scripts tags (static and generated via php) depending on
  context

Load Scenario :

1. master page load pages via $.load jquery function
2. page are inserted and the script is executed (mostly input events or live events)

when i select another page (just imagine a combo with all pages listed), the Load Scenario is executed again...

the 2 js code line that matter in the master page

```
$("#divContent").children().remove(); 
$("#divContent").load("*PAGES-X*");
```

)

Here is the big issues, JQuery **eval** the script code and seem to put then in an Eval Array (in firebug its located at jquery.mins.js/eval/seq/*array number*)
So the js is never unloaded from the eval tab

So if a have some Live event in my pages, the code is executed as many times as the pages have been load ...

**So, i need a way to clean that eval ...** or a automated way to remove all event from a specific scope (because i have others event bind on the Master Page)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

possibly

```
$(selector).die();
```

comes in handy? It will remove all live() bindings for the selected element(s). See http://api.jquery.com/die/ for more info!

Comment: This won't stop global code in those scripts from running (window.load, for instance).

Comment: ok basically you unbinding event on page close i'm aware that could be a requirement but still hoping i can put the evaluated js in a dedicated scope

Comment: It removes all the current live() bindings so that new live() ones can be added withou duplicating existing ones. But then again I might not understand what you want exactly :) It is the problem that every page load might add new live() events that duplicate each other, right?

Comment: right, that and the fact that each page load add some new js code in the jquery eval array and never unload that !!!

Comment: by the way the die() function help me removing the multiple live event so kind of first issue solve ... but i would like to go further and removing unused scripts in memory if i can

Comment: I have never heard of the 'eval tab' or anything similar... Could you reproduce it on JsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Once a script has been loaded, it is impossible, AFAIK, to unload it.

You could use an iframe rather than a div, this way whenever the page is re-loaded you start from a clean slate (within the iframe) once more.

Or alternatively, write your javacsript in a way that will not cause collisions if mulitple scripts are loaded at once.

Comment: That make communication with master page complicated... i need both page to communicate

Comment: @Bgnt44 If they're from the same domain, both pages will be able to communicate with each other via relatively simple javascript. Otherwise, there's the HTML5 postMessage function.

Comment: the pages used a big portion of the global javascript, i definitivly can't isolate the pages code in a iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can try using namespaces.
In your main page :

```
var ws = {};
```

In your loaded content :

```
$( ws.funnyStuff = function() {
// some realy funny stuff here  
});
```

When you're done, you can discard the whole namespace :

```
ws = {};
```

Note: the entry in firebug will remain, I don't known exactly why, but the associated code  won't be executed anymore.